# How to get only the predictions with a probability greater than x

Tags: random-forest, apache-spark-mllib

I used a random forest to classify texts to certain categories. When I used my testdata I got an accuracy of 0.98. But with another set of data the overall accuracy decreases to 0.7. I think, most of the rows still have a high accuracy.

So now I want to show only the predicted categories with a high confidence.
random-forrest gives me a column "probability", which is an array of probabilities. How do I get the actual probabilty of the chosen prediction?

```
val randomForrest = new RandomForestClassifier()
      .setLabelCol(labelIndexer.getOutputCol)
      .setFeaturesCol(vectorAssembler.getOutputCol)
      .setProbabilityCol("probability")
      .setSeed(123)
      .setPredictionCol("prediction")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually came up with the following udf to get the best prediction together with its probability. 
If there is a more convenient way, please comment.

```
def getBestPrediction = udf((
  rawPrediction: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector, probability: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector) => {
  val bestPrediction = probability.argmax
  val bestProbability = probability(bestPrediction)     
  (bestPrediction, bestProbability)
})
```